# SQLite Expo API, no such table in pre-populated file?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo's SQLite API to load a pre-populated db into my project.

I'm using

```
const db = SQLite.openDatabase("data.sqlite");
```

to open it and

```
db.transaction(
  tx => {
    tx.executeSql(`select * from entries`, [], (_, { rows }) =>
      console.log(JSON.stringify(rows))
    );
  },
  (err) => { console.log("Failed Message", err) }
);
```

to run SQL.
This produces this error message:

```
Failed Message [Error: Error code 1: no such table: entries]
```

Also: my file is in the project folder.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the table exits?

Comment: @Markus Yes, and it has ~15,000 records

Comment: Obviously, `openDatabase` looks in another directory.

Comment: @CL. where does it look?

Comment: In the current directory. It's essentially random.

Comment: I'm running into this same issue. I have a backup db file with all the initial data I need and I want the app to start with that, instead of making a blank one. I believe when you're doing SQLite.OpenDatabase it isn't actually looking in the root directory of your app. It's looking elsewhere dependent on the platform. I'm looking for answers right now but I haven't found a straightforward solution yet. Also I noticed this question is from a year ago. Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Its not October 2020 and ive yet to find a solution that works for the current version of expo.

Comment: Any solution guys?